# is there a function to convert sha-1 into sha256

Tags: sha1, sha256

is there a way to convert sha-1 to sha256 for a file. suppose SHA-1 of a files is a14bab81de06e9b590f6cfcd400f90fb5b667eff

Func(a14bab81de06e9b590f6cfcd400f90fb5b667eff) = SHA-256

Here I don't have the original file, else Get-FileHash in powershell would have solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Those are two different hashing algorithms. You cannot get one from the other.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. SHA algorithms need to see all the data in the original files.